# File upload in React and Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, multer

I want to upload an image from the React.js but it is not working.

basically it is not updating the image field and remains the same like following:
[image]

It should update the path of `/images/samples.jpeg` but after I upload the file it remains the same and does not change

The fileUploadHandler:

```
const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", file);
    setUploading(true);

    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      };
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/upload",
        formData,
        config
      );
      setImage(data);
      setUploading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };
```

If I log the `formData` in the **try block** then it does not logs anything so is the `data` field and logs the error as below:
[image]

```
<Form.Group controlId="image">
  <Form.Label>Image</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type="text"
    placeholder="Upload Image url"
    value={image}
    onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
  ></Form.Control>
  <Form.Control
    type="file"
    label="Choose file"
    onChange={uploadFileHandler}
  ></Form.Control>
  {uploading && <Loader />}
</Form.Group>
```

Everything is fine in the backend but still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File input submiting section

```
  onSubmit = async (values) => {
    const { postRequest,  } = this.props
   
    const uploadFileEle = document.getElementById("fileInput")
    let file = uploadFileEle.files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.set('file', file);

    postRequest('image', formData)
   
  }
 <input className="photo-upload" id="fileInput" type="file" onChange={(this.onSubmit)} />
```

axios post section

```
 export const postRequest = (namespace, values, { url = undefined, notification = undefined }={}) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
     
    try {
        dispatch(request(namespace));
        const res = await post(`http://localhost:3000/${namespace}`, values);
    
        if (res.data.errorCode) {
          dispatch(res.data.errorCode, 'error');
        } else {
          dispatch(success(namespace, res.data.result));
       
           dispatch( 'success');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch(failure(namespace, error));
        if (error.response !== undefined) {
          dispatch(error.response.status, 'error');
        } else {
          dispatch('500', 'error');
        }
        throw error;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your axios call :

```
try {
  let result = await axios.post(          // any call like get
    "http://localhost:3000/image",         // your URL
    {                                     // data if post, put
      data: data,
    },{
      headers:config,
    }
  );
  console.log(result.response.data);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error.response.data);
}
```

try to call axios like this.